# Remove duplicates in nested lists in Scheme

Tags: scheme

I'm trying to write a function, `make-set`, in Scheme that takes a list, possibly containing lists, and remove all duplicates. For example `(make-set '(1 (2 3) (2 3)))` should return `(1 (2 3))` and `(make-set '(1 (2 2) 3))` should return `(1 (2) 3)`. This is my code so far:

```
(define make-set
  (lambda (lst)
    (cond ((empty? lst) lst)
          ((not (list? lst)) (list lst))
          ((member? (car lst) (cdr lst))
           (cons (car lst)
                   (make-set (delete (car lst) (cdr lst)))))
          ((list? (car lst))
           (cons (make-set (car lst))
                   (make-set (cdr lst))))
          ((equal? (set-len lst) 1)
           lst)
          (else (cons (car lst) (make-set (cdr lst)))))))
```

which works for the cases I've mentioned. However, if I for example write `(make-set '((1 1) (1 1 1)))` I get the answer `((1) (1))`, so it creates new duplicates. Somehow I want to say that if there's still duplicates it should run the function again, but I don't know how.

(The other functions I've used in `make-set` is `member?` that checks if an element (that can be a list) is in another list, `delete` that deletes all occurrences of an element (that can be a list) from a list and `set-len` that returns the length of a list.)

Comment: What should `(make-set '(1 (2 3) (2 4)))` return?

Comment: Since we spend our free time for you, we'd appreciate some feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with Joshua that the algorithm should me modified to avoid getting into that situation. But I'll first answer your stated question: *Somehow I want to say that if there's still duplicates it should run the function again, but I don't know how.*

This is quite easy actually: just loop until the result is the same as the list you passed:

```
(define make-full-set
  (lambda (lst)
    (let ((r (make-set lst)))
      (if (equal? r lst)
          r
          (make-full-set r)))))
```

Testing:

```
> (make-full-set '((1 1) (1 1 1)))
'((1))
```

Of course this is clumsy and inefficient (needs one additional pass, and expensive list comparisons) so we really need a better algorithm. Here's my take, according to my interpretation, which is that all *atoms* should be unique:

```
(define (make-set lst)

  (define (sub lst items res)
    (if (null? lst)
        (values items (reverse res))
        (let ((c (car lst)))
          (cond
            ((list? c) (let-values (((items2 res2) (sub c items '())))
                         (sub (cdr lst) items2 (if (null? res2) res (cons res2 res)))))
            ((member c items) (sub (cdr lst) items res))
            (else             (sub (cdr lst) (cons c items) (cons c res)))))))

  (let-values (((_ res) (sub lst '() '()))) res))
```

Testing:

```
> (make-set '((1 1) (1 1 1)))
'((1))
> (make-set '(2 (2 3)))
'(2 (3))
> (make-set '(2 (2 3)))
'(2 (3))
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't really specified what's supposed to happen at different levels of the list, e.g., if you start with `(2 (2 3))`, but for the cases that you did specify, the following works. The idea is that you're flattening the elements at each level and *then* removing duplicate elements.  It's a bit of a misnomer to call this `make-set` though, because it's not quite a set that you're trying to get back.  Otherwise, `((1 1) (1 1 1))` would probably return `((1 1) (1 1 1))`, since `(1 1)` is not the same as `(1 1 1)`.  That said, this code works for the examples that you showed.

```
(define (remove-duplicates list)
  (if (null? list)
      list
      (let ((tail (remove-duplicates (cdr list))))
        (if (member (car list) tail)
            tail
            (cons (car list) tail)))))

(define (make-set tree)
  (if (not (pair? tree))
      tree
      (remove-duplicates (map make-set tree))))
```

```
(make-set '((1 1) (1 1 1)))
;=> ((1))

(make-set '(1 (2 3) (2 3)))
;=> (1 (2 3))
```